# CardView shadow not rendered when converted to bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, shadow, android-cardview

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm try to save a view group (which has a `CardView` as one of its childern) as a PNG file. To achieve this,

1. I inflate the view group and populate the views with required information
2. Load an image to an image view via [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
3. Add a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `ViewTreeObserver` of the image view and pass the entire (parent) view that is going to be shared to a method that converts the view to a bitmap *when* image view's bottom is greater than zero (image view's height attribute is set to `wrap_content`, thus its bottom will be zero until image is loaded).

By doing this, I'm able to convert the view to a bitmap, however, with one caveat: the `CardView`'s show is not rendered on the bitmap.

**FAILED ATTEMPTS**

So far I've tried:

1. Switching between `layerType` attribute from "software" to "hardware".
2. Setting on and off `cardUseCompatPadding` attribute of the `CardView`.
3. Tried setting the image drawable without using Glide.
4. Tried without loading an image drawable at all.

**THE CODE**

Here are code snippets that might help you guys identify the problem:

The method used to convert a view to a bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return b;
}
```

XML layout file of the view that's being inflated and passed to the `getBitmapFromView()` above.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/text_subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:gravity="left"
        app:typeface="roboto_medium" />

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/text_subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        app:typeface="roboto_regular" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lessons_horizontal_margin_narrow"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/lessons_image_card_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="@dimen/lessons_image_card_corner_radius"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="@dimen/lessons_image_card_corner_radius" />

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/caption"
                style="@style/text_caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lessons_image_card_caption_margin"
                android:gravity="left"
                app:typeface="roboto_condensed_regular" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Some other views that aren't particularly interesting -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant but maybe you could try setting a small `android:padding`, and `android:clipToPadding="false"` for the cardview?

Comment: Pretty sure its not related to the padding of the parent view or the card view. The shadow renders on screen without any problem and enough room is given to ensure that. Thanks though.

Comment: I face the same problem, though I'm more interested in getting the rounded corners drawn to my canvas. Neither rounded corners, nor shadow gets drawn. I also use view.draw(canvas)

Comment: Same here. Any update on this issue ?

Comment: @galex nope, none :(

Comment: @fahmy seems like shadows are not drawn on views only by calling measure and layout, which is really weird...

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Anyone having any success with this?

Comment: I've had no luck whatsoever. Not even with the answer provided below. No shadow or round corners. Has someone done any progress at all?

Answer (score 4):

just change cardview to view, and set

> android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"

ofcause you need to deal the padding yourself

Comment: While this is not optimal, it worked quite well in my case !!

Answer (score 2):

As @galex said - shadows are not drawn on views only by calling measure and layout.

So we can't use the elevation. Also we can't use the drawable shadow, because then we get sharp angles and straight sides.

**Solution:** use the png 9-path resizable drawable. For this we can use this beautiful tool: [Android shadow generator](https://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

1. Create 9-path files for all of mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.
2. Put all of your png`s to res/drawables folder.
3. Now we can use this drawable like background for view where we want to see shadow.

Note that for different densities, you must change following parameter: height and width of the view, shadow offsets (x and y), blur, round corners radius and paddings.

*Multipliers for diffrent densities:*

```
LDPI - x0.75//practically not used, so you can do without it
MDPI - x1.0// means original size 
HDPI - x1.5
XHDPI - x2.0
XXHDPI - x3.0
XXXHDPI - x4.0
```

**For example** if you need to create rectangle with 30dp x 100dp and radius = 8dp

list of 9.path images you should generate:

1. 30х100px, rad = 8
2. 45х150px, rad = 12
3. 60х200px, rad = 16
4. 90х300px, rad = 24
5. 120х400px, rad = 32

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. So after searching, I founded this. Hope this help
https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9

Comment: Please also provide all the relevant info in your answer. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers, why link-only answers do not fit the format of stack-overflow.